# Insufficient memory when starting NiFi 1.23.2 with Java 11

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to use Java 11 with Apache NiFi 1.23.2.

In the instance I have java 8 and java 11, if with java 8 I configure 8gb of memory for java in the bootstrap.conf file it starts without problem. However, if I change to java 11 and leave these 8gb configured, nifi does not run and reports insufficient memory errors.

```
# JVM memory settings
java.arg.2=-Xms8192m
java.arg.3=-Xmx8192m
```

```
2023-11-16 09:23:24,793 INFO [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdOut # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.

2023-11-16 09:23:24,794 INFO [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdOut # Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 8589934592 bytes for committing reserved memory.

2023-11-16 09:23:24,794 INFO [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdOut # An error report file with more information is saved as:

2023-11-16 09:23:24,794 INFO [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdOut # /opt/nifi/hs_err_pid21924.log
```

I understand that java 11 with respect to java 8 has changed the way of managing the memory, but because I can not assign the 8gb of the instance to java 11 as if it is possible with java 8.

I hope to be able to use java 11 and configure the 8gb available in the instance for the nifi service.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your server/container have enough memory available? NiFi needs non-heap memory as well, so make sure to have at least 2-3 GB more RAM available than your set your heap at. Also, try setting the xms to 2GB or so. It shouldn't be necessary to start with the full 8 GB.

Comment: Is there a flow running already in nifi or is this a first try install?     Agree with Cyrus, you should not need 8 gb min/max.